# Not outputing row with matching WHERE value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am not even sure how to ask this question properly, but here is the problem.
I have a table with 'name', 'email', and 'number' as my columns with an id set as PRIMARY KEY on AUTO_INCREMENT. When I try to find a row like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name='John Doe'` or `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE email='whatever@gmail.com
```

I always get the row I'm looking for without any fuss.
All three columns are VARCHAR with a length of 100.

The 'number' column contains a string of random numbers because I pull those numbers off of an RFID card (hence a database to associate them with names). So when I do

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE number='12334567890'
```

suddenly everything isn't working and returns 0 rows.

Here is where it gets much stranger. If I first query with the number, I get 0 rows, BUT, if I query with a name first (which returns a row) and then I query for the associated number, IT RETURNS A ROW. If I were to query another number, I get 0 rows again, and if I were to query the previous number, I get 0 rows again...

I have so far tried attaching another string to it like `'num 1234567890'`, but that did not help (maybe it was some formatting quirk, I don't know).

I am a beginner when it comes to MySQL, but something as simple as this should be a cake walk, and yet here I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE number LIKE '%12334567890%'
```

try this

Comment: Holy Moly that worked!! Can you explain what that syntax does?

Comment: the thing is that bro, when you are using = it is trying to match the exact number that you are passing. but when you are using LIKE it is finding all the values with that pattern.

Comment: but if your row contain number like this '8541233456789033' then above query return this number also

Comment: yes because of the % sign. that means any number in front and any number in the back, but if the pattern inside is there then it will fetch it

Comment: @sunilwananje, that is strange considering (in my mind) that if I have an exact match to a string and I query for it, that would be more precise than finding patterns, think ID numbers that auto increment for example. Food for thought at least, thank you so much for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

First you understand the where statement, if you are writing where col = "anything" it will match the string with column if it find a match then only it will return the data. In your case its a random number so you cant pull data with where clause unless you know exact value.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE number REGEXP '^[0-9].*$'
```

Comment: The number string I query with is not really random because I have the table where I store the associated numbers to names, and I have a RFID scanner that pulls the numbers and calls a PHP script to query for the matching number.

Comment: Can you give me some sample data which contain by number col